# Xcode 5.0.2 Error: failed to launch issue in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

failed to launch '/private/var/mobile/Applications/E9A264AB-E604-4B42-BBEE-DE629E582DF5/

I'm receiving this error in Xcode only when trying to run the game on my iOS device.  All simulators are working fine.  The game crashes immediately, but I can click on the icon to restart game and it works fine with no issues. I'm new to Xcode.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try what i answered?

Comment: reset the simulator data then try

Answer (score 0):

I assume the test device you have is added to the Member Center. Also, you have valid developer certificate. 
Go to `Build Setting` -> Search "Provisioning Profile" or find it under `Code Signing` -> Pick the valid the provisioning profile associated with your device -> run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0[or your version of iPhone simulator]/Applications`
Delete all builds created. And then clean , build and run your app.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that, you are deploying using `adhoc/distribution` provision. I experienced such error on device when this is the case. If you will install `using IPA` you shouldn't get this error. Also, if you want to debug then you should install via `developer provision`.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are using **AdHoc profile** in which you cant debug. So you can view your logs in **Organizer>Devices>Console**. Or if you want to debug your code at run time then you can use any **Development profile**.